# Cleaning the command line (like `ESC` in Windows)

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, cleanup

When have the garbage in the command line, I can simply hit `escape` and it is cleaned. Nothing happens in Linux. What is the corresponding command? Backspace over the whole string is boring and stupid.

I would like to crosspost to both linux and unix forum, since I think this applies to both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
ctrl+l
```

to clear your screen. Or

```
ctrl+u
```

to clear the line before your cursor. Or

```
ctrl+c
```

to abort your command.

Comment: Also, `Esc` and `dd`, then `i` if using [vi-mode](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: `ctrl+k` kills the line behind your cursor. `ctrl+u` also works when typing passwords e.g. at the sudo prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Use `reset` to clear the terminal all the way up.