# Pressing esc in a terminal window

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

In a Terminal (whether it be UXTerm, Mate Terminal, or a non-X/window system based terminal (not sure if it has an official name) like you get by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), if you press the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow, you can cycle through the history of previously executed commands.

If you then decide you want to execute something completely different, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to clear the line, [as mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/338296/531664). In MS-DOS or Windows' Command Prompt, one can simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Is there a reason why the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key isn't set by default in Ubuntu Terminals to perform the same action as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>?  Is there a way to enable such functionality? I really want to not have to remember a different shortcut key just because I am typing in a different OS.

(I believe my question is not a duplicate of the one whose answer I linked to, because that one is asking for the equivalent shortcut key in Ubuntu, and I am asking for a way to use <kbd>Esc</kbd> or for a reason why it would be a bad idea to set it up this way.)

Comment: Well, one reason not to is that it can be used in some shortcut sequences. I don't know exactly what they are called, which is why I landed here in search of a list of such sequences. One that I use a lot is `Esc .` which inserts the last parameter of the previous command at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind <kbd>ESC</kbd> to the Readline function `unix-line-discard`:

```bsh
bind '"\e": unix-line-discard'
```

To make the change permanent, add the command to `~/.xinputrc`:

```bsh
printf "bind '\"\\\e\": unix-line-discard'\n" >>~/.xinputrc
```

And source `~/.xinputrc` in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
printf 'source ~/.xinputrc\n' >>~/.bashrc
```

To load the change also in the current shell, source `~/.xinputrc`:

```bsh
source ~/.xinputrc
```

This is a Bash feature, so it will work across any terminal, unless the terminal is hijacking the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key itself, for example if <kbd>ESC</kbd> is part of a terminal-specific keystroke, in which case you'll have to disable the offending keystroke in the terminal.

See also `help bind` and `bind -P` for a list of the available Readline functions and the keys / keystrokes they're currently bound to.

Comment: interestingly, this affects the `history` - is there a way to get it not to?

Comment: @KeithHall It shouldn't? What's happening exactly? The `bind` command will be stored in the history of course, but lines discarded by hitting ESC definetly shouldn't be stored.

Comment: let's say I type `ls ~`, press Enter. Then, if I press the up arrow and then press Esc after having bound it, then the `ls ~` no longer exists when I press up or down, and the output from `history` shows a blank entry.

Comment: @KeithHall That looks like a bug: if you notice, the same happens with CTRL+U. Weird.

Comment: so it does! I should have checked that first - sorry to have bothered you with it ;) I see that `ctrl+k` also updates the entry in the history - how annoying (for me)! I'll see if I can find any info about it - thanks for your time :)

Comment: @KeithHall No problem, I never ever even noticed that, so I'm happy you made me aware of that. It's either an undocumented feature or a bug. Well I'll look into that myself as well, I'm curious at this point.

Comment: I think it is intended - [this answer says how to turn it off](http://superuser.com/a/302252/511640)

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know is to show if there is a way to change the link of the keys. 
Maybe there is a setting of that in the terminal program you use.